InputStream misses some bytes reading file via FTP
I'm trying to download a ZIP file on Android via FTP.
Problem is that sometimes the received file has some bytes missing towards the end.
This doesn't happen using InputStream/OutputStream on local files.
It's not a problem of the file: I tested with many different files with same results.
It's not a problem of the server: I tested on two different with same results.
It doesn't even seem like a connection problem: tested with two different connections, same problem.
And moreover seems not a problem specifically of Apache FTPClient: I tryed the old ftp4j and produces equally missing bytes towards the end of file.
For my comprehension it's InputStream.read() that doesn't properly do its job, missing one byte at the end of some buffers.
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

fun downloadFile(remotePath: String, outputFile: File) {
    val client = FTPClient()
    client.connect("ftp.example.com")
    client.login("username", "password")
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode()
    println(client.getSize(remotePath)) // Say 100000 bytes
    //client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE) // Doesn't matter
    client.retrieveFileStream(remotePath).use { inputStream ->
        outputFile.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) // 8 * 1024
            var bytes: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytes = it } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
            }
        }
    }
    client.completePendingCommand()
    client.disconnect()
    println(outputFile.length()) // Usually 100000, other times 99999 or less bytes
}

lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    downloadFile("/path/to/input.zip", File(cacheDir, "output.zip"))
}

The file to use for testing could be any file larger than the buffer, also a plain ASCII file.
Obviously bigger is and more probably becomes corrupted.
How can I properly retrieve a binary file via FTP?
Edit
This issue affects only emulators. I can't reproduce it on physical devices.
I tested downloading a 300 KB file, filled only with 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789...
I added checks to see if some byte is missing inside or at the end of the buffer:
fun downloadFile(remotePath: String, outputFile: File) {
    ...
    println("Input size: " + client.getSize(remotePath))
    client.retrieveFileStream(remotePath).use { inputStream ->
        outputFile.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            var bytes: Int
            var count = 0
            var lastPrev: Byte = '9'.code.toByte()
            var firstNext: Byte
            var prevBytes = 0
            var totalBytes: Long = 0
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytes = it } != -1) {
                count++
                firstNext = buffer[0]
                checkSequence(buffer, bytes, count)
                if (!checkJunction(lastPrev, firstNext))
                    println(
                        "Incoherent start of buffer $count: " +
                                "${lastPrev.toInt().toChar()}-${firstNext.toInt().toChar()} ($prevBytes, $bytes)"
                    )
                lastPrev = buffer[bytes - 1]
                prevBytes = bytes
                totalBytes += bytes
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
            }
            if (!checkJunction(lastPrev, '0'.code.toByte()))
                println("Missing end of buffer $count: ${lastPrev.toInt().toChar()} ($prevBytes)")
            println("Total $count buffers: $totalBytes")
        }
    }
    client.completePendingCommand()
    client.disconnect()
    println("Final size: ${outputFile.length()}") // Always equal to totalBytes
}

private fun checkSequence(buffer: ByteArray, bytes: Int, count: Int) {
    val nine = '9'.code.toByte()
    val zero = '0'.code.toByte()
    for (i in 0 until bytes - 1) {
        val ok = if (buffer[i] == nine) buffer[i + 1] == zero else buffer[i + 1] == buffer[i].inc()
        if (!ok) println(
            "Broken buffer $count: ${buffer[i].toInt().toChar()}${buffer[i + 1].toInt().toChar()} ($i of $bytes)"
        )
    }
}

private fun checkJunction(lastPrev: Byte, firstNext: Byte): Boolean {
    return if (lastPrev == '9'.code.toByte()) firstNext == '0'.code.toByte()
    else firstNext == lastPrev.inc()
}

Normally the output is like this:

Input size: 300000
Total 68 buffers: 300000
Final size: 300000

But sometimes could be something like this:

Input size: 300000
Incoherent start of buffer 176: 8-0 (1438, 1)
Incoherent start of buffer 179: 8-0 (1439, 1440)
Incoherent start of buffer 181: 8-0 (2879, 1440)
Incoherent start of buffer 184: 8-0 (1439, 1)
Broken buffer 185: 80 (4317 of 5758)
Incoherent start of buffer 187: 8-0 (2879, 1)
Missing end of buffer 191: 8 (1439)
Total 191 buffers: 299993
Final size: 299993

The problem is always one missing byte at the end or inside some buffers.
Affected buffers are towards the end of input stream.
It's always a 9 that is missing, also inside the buffer.

After your while loop ends, add outputStream.flush() and something like (outputStream as? FileOutputStream)?.getFd()?.sync(), to ensure the results are fully written to disk before proceeding.

@CommonsWare Just tryed with both outputStream.flush() and outputStream.fd?.sync(): same corrupted files.
The problem seems before, on how read() fills each buffer, missing sometimes one byte at the end of the buffer (and returning the corresponding wrong bytes number).

@CommonsWare No wait a minute... Adding outputStream.fd?.sync() just after outputStream.write() inside the while loop seems to increase drastically the files correctly downloaded!

OK, that's good to hear. You could also try eliminating the whole loop using copyTo().

@CommonsWare I'm afraid not, because copyTo() internally has a while loop that's pretty much identical to the one I used, and fd.sync() apparently needs to be placed inside this loop, not after.

@CommonsWare I'm afraid your advice doesn't make sense to me. If the problem is fixed by sync'ing the output stream's FD, then the problem would be with the outputstream. But it seems the problem is actually with the inputstream, since the OP says it only happens when downloading a file from FTP. If it was an outputstream problem, it would also happen when reading local files.

@Salvador can you please take the outputstream completely out of the equation by just writing the count of bytes read, instead of the full file contents. Then we can tell if the problem is with reading the file. Also, can you tell if the missing bytes are at the end of each buffer, or only at the end of the file?

@k314159 I added checks on the inputstream taking the outputstream out: the problem actually is in the inputstream. Missing bytes are at the end and also inside some buffers. See my edit.
